# Mac Pro Book Crashes from time to time

Tags: macos, mac

My work mac pro book keeps crashing from time to time. It could be days or hours apart. Do you know what could be causing this? I am on OX Yosemite 10.10.5

```
Anonymous UUID:       559EA92D-CB4A-057F-506D-D5D22A812721

Wed Dec 16 11:51:11 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 7 caller 0xffffff800e216df2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800e698387, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000000000140, CR3: 0x0000000000532019, CR4: 0x00000000001627e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000140, RBX: 0xffffff804e504008, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff81f6ccb958, RBP: 0xffffff81f6ccb9a0, RSI: 0x0000000000000140, RDI: 0x00000000ffffffff
R8:  0xffffff8032a466d0, R9:  0x000000000000000b, R10: 0xffffff80450d8708, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0xffffff804d206a50, R13: 0xffffff8037a9e008, R14: 0xffffff8044f39f00, R15: 0xffffff804e504208
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff800e698387, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000140, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x7

Backtrace (CPU 7), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81f6ccb600 : 0xffffff800e12ad21 
0xffffff81f6ccb680 : 0xffffff800e216df2 
0xffffff81f6ccb840 : 0xffffff800e233ca3 
0xffffff81f6ccb860 : 0xffffff800e698387 
0xffffff81f6ccb9a0 : 0xffffff800e3468f0 
0xffffff81f6ccba20 : 0xffffff800e3463da 
0xffffff81f6ccba70 : 0xffffff800e3409c4 
0xffffff81f6ccbae0 : 0xffffff800e34b91a 
0xffffff81f6ccbb80 : 0xffffff800e3495e4 
0xffffff81f6ccbd90 : 0xffffff800e5df717 
0xffffff81f6ccbe20 : 0xffffff800e5dec71 
0xffffff81f6ccbf50 : 0xffffff800e64b376 
0xffffff81f6ccbfb0 : 0xffffff800e2344a6 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: KernelEventAgent

Mac OS version:
14F1021

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Tue Sep  1 21:23:09 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.50.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 06D286E3-A8A1-3BE7-A7EB-EAC6E0C69758
Kernel slide:     0x000000000de00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800e000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800df00000
System model name: MacBookPro11,4 (Mac-06F11FD93F0323C5)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 45158693598177
last loaded kext at 44566646203950: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard    176.2 (addr 0xffffff7f909b1000, size 12288)
last unloaded kext at 44639075758684: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC  4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7f90960000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.parallels.kext.vnic 11.0.2 31348
com.parallels.kext.netbridge    11.0.2 31348
com.parallels.kext.hypervisor   11.0.2 31348
com.parallels.kext.usbconnect   11.0.2 31348
foo.tap 1.0
foo.tun 1.0
org.pqrs.driver.Karabiner   10.11.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleIntelI210Ethernet  2.2.0b1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   85.3
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.2
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 67
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTopCaseDriver  67
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.2.0d4
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.6
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.7.4
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.36.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.12
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard    176.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  295.23
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter   2.0.2
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.6f3
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  264.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriverPM    710.4.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   176.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18.3
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18.3
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.25
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.16
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.25
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.30.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 398
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro11,4, BootROM MBP114.0172.B06, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.29f24
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533642465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533642465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x152), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.6f3 16238, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 2, Ethernet, en4
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
PCI Card: pci1b73,1100, USB eXtensible Host Controller, Thunderbolt@194,0,0
PCI Card: ethernet, Ethernet Controller, Thunderbolt@193,0,0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256G, 251 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: USB audio CODEC
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
Thunderbolt Device: Thunderbolt 2 Express Dock HD, Belkin International, Inc., 3, 25.1
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a good possibility you have a hard drive that is starting to fail. You should 1)make sure you back up your data immediately, and 2) run diagnostics on the drive.